# Records deleted but the size of the table doesn't change

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have a MySql table (MyISAM) with 25.000 records and 1.8 MB size.
The structure of the table is like this

```
CREATE TABLE `t_prs_info` (
`id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`exam_kod` MEDIUMINT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`mss` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`grp` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
`class` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
`gp` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
`vrnt` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
`xdil` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
`cns` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
`surname` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
`cl_kod` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`prs_kod` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`phone` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

When I try to execute SQL command to delete some rows

```
DELETE FROM t_pers_info WHERE exam_kod=1000
```

it deletes the records but the size of the table doesn't change.

Comment: please restart your pc and then check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE `t_prs_info`
```

after deleting

Answer (score 1):

Try to optimize your table http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html